# Desanidar diccionario en Dataframe_Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buen dia,

Tengo un problema en desanidar lo siguiente

```
df=
    Node1                               ; Node2
0   (22, {'Y': '996.3', 'X': 773.6})    ;(56, {'Y': '996.1', 'X': 773.1})
1   (23, {'Y': '996.5', 'X': 773.8})    ;(57, {'Y': '996.30', 'X': 773.2})
2   (24, {'Y': '996.8', 'X': 773.6})    ;(58, {'Y': '996.16', 'X': 773.69})
3   (25, {'Y': '996.7', 'X': 773.6})    ;(59, {'Y': '996.60', 'X': 773.15})
[4 rows x 2 columns]

type(df)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Como puedo desanidar y convertir este Dataframe en lo siguiente:

```
      Node1                ; Node2
     Num1 ; Y1;  X1      ;Num2; Y2;  X2 
0   22; 996.3; 773.6     ;56;  996.1;  773.1
1   23; 996.5; 773.8     ;57; 996.30;  773.2
2   24; 996.8; 773.6     ;58;  996.16; 773.69
3   25; 996.7; 773.6     ;59; 996.60; 773.15
```

Quedare agradecido con su ayuda o alguna idea de como lo podría realizar.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias dificultades con tus datos de entrada. Además de que cada celda de tu dataframe es una tupla, y el segundo elemento de la tupla es un diccionario, encima los valores del diccionario son cadenas (en la `Y`) o floats (en la `X`). Entiendo que quieres convertirlos todos el `float` para tu estructura final.

Esta es el valor de `df` que usaré como entrada, igual al que tú has proporcionado, tal como lo muestra un `print()`:

```
>>> print(df)
                              Node1                               Node2
0  (22, {'Y': '996.3', 'X': 773.6})    (56, {'Y': '996.1', 'X': 773.1})
1  (23, {'Y': '996.5', 'X': 773.8})   (57, {'Y': '996.30', 'X': 773.2})
2  (24, {'Y': '996.8', 'X': 773.6})  (58, {'Y': '996.16', 'X': 773.69})
3  (25, {'Y': '996.7', 'X': 773.6})  (59, {'Y': '996.60', 'X': 773.15})
```

Lo primero que se me ocurre es tomar una columna, por ejemplo `df.Node1` y usar sus valores para crear un nuevo dataframe, usando `pd.DataFrame.from_items()`, pues este constructor espera que le pase una lista cuyos elementos son tuplas (coincide) cuyos segundos elementos han de ser diccionarios (coincide también).

No obstante no produce el resultado deseado:

```
>>> print(pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(df.Node1)))
      22     23     24     25
X  773.6  773.8  773.6  773.6
Y  996.3  996.5  996.8  996.7
```

Pero estamos muy cerca. Si hacemos la transpuesta de esto (operador `.T`) que cambia filas por columnas, ya casi lo tenemos. De paso puedo usar `.applymap()` para que convierta a `float` todos los elementos:

```
>>> print(pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(df.Node1)).T.applymap(float))
        X      Y
22  773.6  996.3
23  773.8  996.5
24  773.6  996.8
25  773.6  996.7
```

Tan sólo faltaría que los números 22, 23, 24, 25, en lugar de ser el índice, fuesen otra columna llamada "Num1", y renombrar las columnas "X", "Y" para que sean "X1", "Y1". Esto puede hacerse dando al índice el nombre "Num1" y después haciendo un `reset_index()`.

Una vez hecho eso, podemos hacer lo mismo con la columna `Num2` y finalmente usar `pd.concat()` para concatenar los dataframes obtenidos en cada caso.

El siguiente código implementa estas ideas:

```
p1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(df.Node1)).T.applymap(float)
p1.index.name = "Num1"
p1.columns = ["X1", "Y1"]
p1.reset_index(inplace=True)

p2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(df.Node2)).T.applymap(float)
p2.index.name = "Num2"
p2.columns = ["X2", "Y2"]
p2.reset_index(inplace=True)
r = pd.concat([p1, p2], axis=1)
```

El resultado en `r` es:

```
   Num1     X1     Y1  Num2      X2      Y2
0    22  773.6  996.3    56  773.10  996.10
1    23  773.8  996.5    57  773.20  996.30
2    24  773.6  996.8    58  773.69  996.16
3    25  773.6  996.7    59  773.15  996.60
```

### Nota adicional

No tengo del todo claro si quieres que además las columnas sean jerárquicas, es decir, que tengan las cabeceras "Node1" y "Node2" agrupando a las tres columnas respectivas. Si éste fuera el caso, basta cambiar la última línea a:

```
r = pd.concat([p1, p2], axis=1, keys=["Node1", "Node2"])
```

para obtener:

```
  Node1               Node2                
   Num1     X1     Y1  Num2      X2      Y2
0    22  773.6  996.3    56  773.10  996.10
1    23  773.8  996.5    57  773.20  996.30
2    24  773.6  996.8    58  773.69  996.16
3    25  773.6  996.7    59  773.15  996.60
```

aunque en este caso yo no veo sentido a "renombrar" las columnas X, Y para que sean X1, Y1 y X2, Y2. Perfectamente podrían conservar sus nombres originales (y las columnas Num1 y Num2 llamarse ambas Num). Es decir:

```
p1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(df.Node1)).T.applymap(float)
p1.index.name = "Num"
p1.reset_index(inplace=True)

p2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(list(df.Node2)).T.applymap(float)
p2.index.name = "Num"
p2.reset_index(inplace=True)
r = pd.concat([p1, p2], axis=1, keys=["Node1", "Node2"])
```

Resultando en:

```
  Node1               Node2                
    Num      X      Y   Num       X       Y
0    22  773.6  996.3    56  773.10  996.10
1    23  773.8  996.5    57  773.20  996.30
2    24  773.6  996.8    58  773.69  996.16
3    25  773.6  996.7    59  773.15  996.60
```

No hay ambigüedad en esos nombre repetidos, debido a la jerarquía. Para acceder por ejemplo a la columna X del Node2 podrías poner:

```
r[("Node2", "X")]
```

```
0    773.10
1    773.20
2    773.69
3    773.15
Name: (Node2, X), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Se me aclaro algunas cosas que no entendía, muchas gracias por su ayuda fue muy claro. Lo voy a implementar, muchas gracias. Saludos cordiales